# Distinguishing which request was handled by which server

Tags: windows, web-server

I've got single virtual machine that runs multiple http servers. Those servers are totally different as they do different things, they use different technologies (some are .NET, others are python, others are php => apache (windows)). All of these servers has generally different path, some of directories are duplicated, some turned off, some may be hidden (I just don't know anything about them). Generally there is a lot of mess here. 
I've got two links

```
link A => http://myserver/a
link B => http://myserver/b
```

How would I find out which server handles which request assuming I don't know anything about the enviroment and also assuming that I do have access to this machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple HTTP servers serving the same HTTP hostname, you will have some kind of reverse proxy in front of all this that will route the incoming connections to different backend services. Search for this as a first step.

Second step: Look into the configuration for your various HTTP servers to learn what they are responding to and understand how this relates to the frontend proxy configuration.